# Como acessar uma propriedade de um objeto para compor o valor de outra propriedade?

Tags: javascript, propriedade, this

Estou tentando acessar a propriedade `nome` com `this.nome` na propriedade `frase` e estou recebendo o valor `undefined`.

Gostaria de saber porque não estou recebendo o valor que atribuí.

```js
let livro = ['O senhor dos anéis', 1954, 'J. R. R. Tolkien'];

let objeto = {
    nome: livro[0].toUpperCase(),
    totalAnos: 2050 - livro[1],
    frase: this.nome + ' por ' + livro[2],
};

console.log(objeto);
```

Saída:

```
{
  "nome": "O SENHOR DOS ANÉIS",
  "totalAnos": 96,
  "frase": "undefined por J. R. R. Tolkien"
}
```

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 3):

Diferente do que ocorre em uma [função construtora](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#usando_uma_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_construtora), dentro do contexto duma [expressão de objeto literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#criando_objetos) a variável [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) é ligada ao [objeto global](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Global_object)(em [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) `this` tem seu valor `undefined`).

Então quando faz `frase: this.nome + ' por ' + livro[2]` o valor de `this` no navegador será o objeto [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window) enquanto no Node.js será o objeto [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global), o que causa o comportamento percebido na pergunta.

**Porém**, dentro do contexto de um [método ou *getter*/*setter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#como_m%C3%A9todo_de_um_objeto) `this` é ligado valor do objeto proprietário do método, ou *getter*/*setter*, chamado.

> - [*Getter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) é a sintaxe `get` que associa a uma propriedade de um
>   objeto a uma função que será chamada quando tal propriedade é lida.
> - [*Setter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) é sintaxe `set` que associa a uma propriedade de um
>   objeto uma função para ser chamada quando houver tentativa de definir
>   valor para essa propriedade.

Apenas modifique a propriedade `frase` para que seja um *getter*, que `this` dentro  do contexto da função associada será ligado ao objeto proprietário da propriedade.

```js
let livro = ['O senhor dos anéis', 1954, 'J. R. R. Tolkien']

let objeto = {
  nome: livro[0].toUpperCase(),
  totalAnos: 2050 - livro[1],
  get frase() {
    return this.nome + ' por ' + livro[2]
  },
}

console.log(objeto)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode se referir ao próprio objeto no momento da declaração. Seria preciso fazer algo assim:

```js
let livro = ['O senhor dos anéis', 1954, 'J. R. R. Tolkien']
let objeto = {
    nome: livro[0].toUpperCase(),
    totalAnos: 2050 - livro[1],
}
objeto.frase = objeto.nome + ' por ' + livro[2]
console.log(objeto)
```